# How to replace placeholders in a multiline text in powershell

Tags: powershell

The `obj` object has properties `Name` and `Age`. How can I replace them in the `foreach` loop.
This method should return the Json string.

**Function:**

```
function Get-JsonFileContent {    
    param(
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$objects
    )
    $includeBlocks = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();
    foreach ($obj in $objects) {
        $include = @"
                {
                    "name": "$obj.Name",
                    "age": "$obj.Age"                    
                }
    "@
      $includeBlocks.Add($include);
    }
  Write-Host $includeBlocks;
  return $($includeBlocks -join ",");
}
```

The `Write-Host` command gives this output:

```
{
    "name": @{Name=John Doe; Age=30}.Name,
    "age": @{Name=John Doe; Age=30}.Age
},
{
    "name": @{Name=Jane Doe; Age=40}.Name,
    "age": @{Name=Jane Doe; Age=40}.Age
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "age": "30"                    
},
{
   "name": "Jane Doe",
   "age": "40"                    
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$includeBlocks | ConvertTo-Json`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM That gives an error as the JSON is not formatted. I have updated the question with the current output. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fuller answer you can review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145704/how-can-you-use-an-objects-property-in-a-double-quoted-string)

You need to force evaluation by surrounding it by $().  The corrected code is below.

```
function Get-JsonFileContent {    
    param(
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$objects
    )
    $includeBlocks = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();
    foreach ($obj in $objects) {
        $include = @"
                {
                    "name": "$($obj.Name)",
                    "age": "$($obj.Age)"                    
                }
    "@
      $includeBlocks.Add($include);
    }
  Write-Host $includeBlocks;
  return $($includeBlocks -join ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **subexpression** i.e. `$(expression)` to achieve the result. Something like:

```bash
function Get-JsonFileContent {
    param(
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$objects
    )
    $includeBlocks = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();
    foreach ($obj in $objects) {
        $include = @"
                {
                    "name": "$($obj.Name)", # <---- notice this
                    "age": "$($obj.Age)"    # <---- and this                
                }
    "@
        $includeBlocks.Add($include);
    }
    Write-Host $includeBlocks;
    return $($includeBlocks -join ",");
}
```